# Can Raspberry Pi Zero ‘W’ route wlan0 traffic to usb0?

Tags: wifi, usb

I’m trying to turn a Pi-Zero W into a USB WiFi dongle but have not found any instructions or much about the possibility. What I have tried hasn’t worked. Now I wonder if it is even possible to route packets to the usb port. Am I wasting my time? Can anyone clear this up?

Comment: Do you realise you can but a USB WiFi dongle  for less than the price of a Pi?

Comment: This is not about cost, it is about size and capability.

Comment: Dongles are smaller and more capable

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you try to achieve.

You want that your raspberry behaves like a USB network device on the USB side?

And on the Wifi side shall it act like a WLAN access point or like a Wifi client connecting to a predefined access point?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. I have the Pi-Zero configured as a USB “RNDIS gadget” and also connected to my WiFi AP, and figure I might as well add WiFi packet routing to usb0.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a Raspberry Pi Zero W available but you can use [ethernet gadget mode](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=gadget+mode). Then the **usb0** interface behaves like a normal network interface and you can enable **ip forwarding**. This will forward network traffic between the available network interfaces, in your case **wlan0** and **usb0**. You can enable it with:

```
rpi ~$ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# check with:
rpi ~$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

but this setting is lost on next bootup. To have it persistent you can set it in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. There you have to uncomment the line:

```
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

It is possible that you also have to add/modify the routing table for your configuration to get traffic routed between the networks that the interfaces are connected to.